# How do I add a textblock dynamically to a page?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm just learning how to make universal apps for windows 10. Most of the tutorials show you how to work with XAML and how to assign functions to elements when you click on them but I couldn't find a way to make a new control appear when I click a button.

I'm making a note taking application. I've designed most of the stuff that I need. Now I want whenever I click a button to create a new textblock where the user can write their note.

```
    //Create a new note when clicking the add button
    private void newNoteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox newNote = new TextBox();
        newNote.Text = "Enter your text";
    }
```

This is the code that runs when the button is clicked. When I run the application nothing happens. I think I have to put the new textbox in some kind of `Grid` or something.

Most of the tutorials are really old or mention windows forms and use some sort of `this.Controls.Add(newNote);` but Visual studio doesn't give me the Controls.Add option. I've also created a `<Grid x:Name="notes"></Grid>` which I thought I could use as a placeholder for the notes that are being created but I can't access the `Grid` element through the code.

Comment: You need to add the new control to an existing parent control (or to a window directly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Container Controls like `Grid` have [`Children`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property so you should use `Childern` like this:

```
TextBox newNote = new TextBox();
newNote.Text = "Enter your text";
notes.Childern.Add(newNote);
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something like that.

Comment: any tips on how to make the new notes appear next to each other instead of on top of each other?

Comment: @captain...I think it would be better using another container like `StackPanel`.

Comment: @captain... And set the `Orientation="Horizontal"` of the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 2):

When defining

```
<Grid x:Name="notes"></Grid>
```

in XAML on the page, you be able to use `notes` as the identifier to access this `Grid` from the page's code behind:

```
notes.Children.Add(newNote);
```